# How can I get a SVM that has been trained on a bigger matrix to classify a different size matrix

Tags: matlab, image-processing, classification, svm

I am training a one vs all svm classifier. I used a 200 by 459 matrix to train the classifier using VLFeat svm classifier. (http://www.vlfeat.org/matlab/vl_svmtrain.html)

```
[W B] = vl_svmtrain(train_image_feats', tmp', .00001);
```

where `train_image_feats'` is a 200 by 459 matrix, and `tmp'` is the label matrix which is 1 by 459 vector.

The above command trains the svm with no problem, but then to classify the scores obtained on the test matrix I get an error. The test matrix is obviously not of the same size as that of the training matrix.

```
   scores(i, :) = W'*test_image_feats' + B;
```

Where `test_image_feats'` is a 200 by 90 matrix. `scores` is a 9 by 459 matrix. 9 Because there are 9 categories(labels) to classify and 459 are the number of training images.

The above command gives the error:

> Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.
>
> Error in svm_classify (line 56)    scores(i, :) = W'*test_image_feats'
>   + B;

Edit: Full code added..

```
categories = unique(train_labels); 
num_categories = length(categories);
scores = zeros([num_categories size(train_labels, 1)]); %train_labels is 459 by 1 size
for i=1:num_categories %there are 9 categories
   tmp = strcmp(train_labels, categories{i});
   tmp = tmp - (1-tmp);
   [W B] = vl_svmtrain(train_image_feats', tmp', .00001);
   scores(i, :) = W'*test_image_feats' + B;
end
predicted_categories = cell(size(train_labels));
parfor i=1:size(test_image_feats,1)
    image_scores = scores(:, i);
    label_index = find(image_scores==max(image_scores));
    predicted_categories{i}=categories(label_index);
end
```

Comment: It seems to me that you're mixing test and train cases. I assume that after training the model you use it to predict 90 test images?

Comment: So? What `size`s are `W'` and `B`? And what `size` is `W'*test_image_feats' + B`?

Comment: W' is a 1 by 200 matrix and B is a scalar value (off set value)

Comment: Could you provide more code? For me the size of "score" doesn't make any sense. What is it supposed to be? The prediction score for your test cases? In that case it should be 9 by 90, not 9 by 459. Also you say that there are 9 labels, but are those nine labels specified cohenrently in "tmp"?

Comment: @AdrienNK Yes that is correct. Strange thing is that if I use 459 images (9 classes with 51 images each) for training and then same amount for testing it goes fine. But if with the same model if I test 90 images (10 images from each class) using same code I get this error.

Comment: You try to predict the score for 90 images and you use a matrix that can contain 459 scores for that. "scores" have to be 9*"number of test images".

Comment: @AdrienNK Full code added in edit.

Comment: Have a look on this page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36758770/how-to-adapt-hog-features-vector-to-linear-svm-input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually you are training a model with 459 training samples to predict the scores of 90 test samples.

```
scores = zeros([num_categories size(train_labels, 1)]);
```

isn't right as it will be the size of the training set. In fact you don't have to care at all about the size of the training set, you could train the model with 20 or 20000 images the prediction step shouldn't be any different.

`scores` have to be defined with the test case in mind

```
scores = zeros([num_categories size(test_labels, 1)]);
```

When you used 459 for both it only worked because `size(test_labels, 1)` was equal to `size(train_labels, 1)`

Comment: Thank you that was the solution. I knew the size was different but did not edit it because 90 is smaller than 459, so in theory it should have utilized the 90 columns and left the rest as 0. I thought problems arise when matrices are smaller than the required amount. But I guess thats not how it works.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with your right hand side of the assignment, but with `score(i,:)`: you are trying to assign a 9-by-90 size matrix into a **single** row of `score` - this simply won't fit.

Comment: Obviously, the error message is pretty clear about that. But for me the line doesn't make sense from a conceptual point of view.

Comment: As *obvious* as it may seem to you, it was still what the OP asked. And this answer explains the error message.

Comment: "The test matrix is obviously not of the same size as that of the training matrix." from OP's question. This was not really what OP was asking, but anyway...